# Conditional JsonProperty using Jackson with Spring Boot

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

A Spring Boot application is tasked with updating a remote integration API every so many minutes. This application can be deployed to a test or prod environment, the application is informed of the end point it should be looking at through an "application.properties" flag. A POJO is being serialized with Jackson and pushed to the endpoint, with the JsonProperty annotations containing the field IDs for the API that it is being pushed to.

ie

```
@JsonProperty("field_001)
private String name;

@JsonProperty("field_002)
private String address;
```

The field labels for these values differ on the test endpoint. So the test endpoint might expect the properties to map as

```
@JsonProperty("field_005)
private String name;

@JsonProperty("field_006)
private String address;
```

I would like to be able to utilize the Spring Boot native support for profile based properties files. To read in the JsonProperty annotation values at run time from an external properties file.

So for example,

There might be three files application.properties, application-test.properties and application-prod.properties.
Spring Boot could read in the test or prod properties in addition to the vanilla properties file based on the "spring.profiles.active" setting.

...-test.properties would contain the constant values for the test server fields. And ...-prod.properties would contain the constant values for the prod server fields.

Nesting annotations such as Spring's @Value tag, like this:

```
@JsonProperty(@Value("${property.file.reference.here}))
```

doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 5):

I apologize for reviving an old question however I still was not able to find satisfying answer.

Here's my solution using extended `JacksonAnnotationIntrospector` which allows to use `${environment.properties}` within `@JsonProperty` annotation

First extend the introspector

```
public class DynamicJacksonAnnotationIntrospector extends JacksonAnnotationIntrospector {
    private final Environment environment;

    public DynamicJacksonAnnotationIntrospector(Environment environment) {
        this.environment = environment;
    }

    @Override
    public PropertyName findNameForSerialization(Annotated a) {
        PropertyName name = super.findNameForSerialization(a);
        if (name == null) {
            return null;
        }
        String simpleName = name.getSimpleName();
        return PropertyName.construct(environment.resolvePlaceholders(simpleName), name.getNamespace());
    }
    //For deserialization I think the same mechanism could be used,
    //just override `findNameForDeserialization`, although I haven't tested it
}
```

Then use it with `ObjectMapper` configuration

```
@Configuration
public class ObjectMapperConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper getObjectMapper(DynamicJacksonAnnotationIntrospector introspector) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        SerializationConfig config = mapper.getSerializationConfig().withInsertedAnnotationIntrospector(introspector);
        mapper.setConfig(config);
        return mapper;
    }

    @Bean
    public DynamicJacksonAnnotationIntrospector introspector(Environment environment) {
        return new DynamicJacksonAnnotationIntrospector(environment);
    }
}
```

Examples:

```
public class DynamicTestClass {
    @JsonProperty("${dynamic.property.name}")
    private String dynamicPropertyName;
    //getters/setters
}
```

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = [
        ObjectMapperConfiguration
])
@TestPropertySource("classpath:test.properties")
class DynamicJacksonAnnotationIntrospectorTest extends Specification {
    @Autowired
    ObjectMapper mapper

    def "should find name for serialization from properties"() {
        def bean = new DynamicTestClass()
        bean.dynamicPropertyName = "qwerty"

        when:
        def result = mapper.writeValueAsString(bean)

        then:
        result == "{\"overriddenName\":\"qwerty\"}"
    }
}
```

test.properties

```
dynamic.property.name=overriddenName
```

The solution is reverse compatible so you can still use constant values in `@JsonProperty`

Comment: This was exactly what I needed, many thanks. To make it work for deserialization, basically copy the serialization code, but make sure to call super.findNameForDeserialization, and make sure to also set a DeserializationConfig on the object mapper and you´re good to go.

Comment: @Matiz 
What versions of the libraries did you use?

I am getting error when I use your code.

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Conflicting/ambiguous property name definitions (implicit name 'dynamicPropertyName'): found multiple explicit names: [${dynamic.property.name}, overriddenName], but also implicit accessor: [method com.severstal.jirasm.core.dto.jira.webhook.issue.DynamicTestClass#getDynamicPropertyName(0 params)][visible=true,ignore=false,explicitName=false]`

Comment: @AlexeyOsetsky were you able to solve the problem you mentioned? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @mint  I could not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you will be able to do this using Spring Expression Language (SpEL) inside of a Jackson annotation, as you are trying (with or without the `@Value` annotation).

I would do this by creating a `JsonSerializer<YourPojo>` and/or `JsonDeserializer<YourPojo>` that takes in your SpEL expressions and creates (or reads) using the provided field names.

```
//make me a spring managed bean!
public class PojoSerializer extends JsonSerializer<YourPojo> {
    @Value("${property.file.reference.name")
    private String nameField;

    @Value("${property.file.reference.address")
    private String addrField;

    @Override
    public void serialize(YourPojo pojo, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        jgen.writeStartObject();
        jgen.writeStringField(nameField, pojo.getName());
        jgen.writeStringField(addrField, pojo.getAddress());
        jgen.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

Being that this is a Spring managed bean, you would need to plug this into your Spring managed `ObjectMapper`.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = //my ObjectMapper from spring
PojoSerializer pojoSerializer = //my PojoSerializer from spring

SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("MyModule", new Version(1, 0, 0, null));
module.addSerializer(YourPojo.class, pojoSerializer);
mapper.registerModule(module);
```

Some of this might not be necessary with SpringBoot's AutoConfiguration.  I am generally unaware to what SpringBoot will pick up for its Jackson AutoConfiguration, but `JsonSerializer` and `JsonDeserializer` might be autoregistered if they are in the `ApplicationContext`.

Comment: Could a serializer be used to dictate the serialization of only a few fields on the POJO? There are close to thirty fields that do _not_ change depending on the environment. Ideally the serializer could encompass the logic needed to serialize the server specific fields, but let the @JsonProperty values on the POJO handle the rest.

Comment: I doubt it, but I will point out that I don't know for certain.

Answer (score 0):

This is [Matiz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5372166/matiz) 's augmented answer.

Solution using extended `JacksonAnnotationIntrospector` which allows to use `${environment.properties}` within `@JsonProperty` annotation

```
public class DynamicJacksonAnnotationIntrospector extends JacksonAnnotationIntrospector {
    private final Environment environment;

    public DynamicJacksonAnnotationIntrospector(Environment environment) {
        this.environment = environment;
    }

    @Override
    public PropertyName findNameForSerialization(Annotated a) {
        return injectEnvironmentInJsonProperty(super.findNameForSerialization(a));
    }

    @Override
    public PropertyName findNameForDeserialization(Annotated a){
        return injectEnvironmentInJsonProperty(super.findNameForDeserialization(a));
    }

    @Override
    public PropertyName findRootName(AnnotatedClass ac) {
        return injectEnvironmentInJsonProperty(super.findNameForDeserialization(ac));
    }

    private PropertyName injectEnvironmentInJsonProperty(PropertyName name){
        if (name == null) {
            return null;
        }
        String simpleName = name.getSimpleName();
        log.info(environment.resolvePlaceholders(simpleName));
        return PropertyName.construct(environment.resolvePlaceholders(simpleName), name.getNamespace());
    }
}
```

Create webconfig class for entity recognition in controller.

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private final ApplicationContext context;

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        //JSON
        AnnotationIntrospector pairedIntrospectors = AnnotationIntrospector.pair(introspector(context.getEnvironment()),
                new JacksonAnnotationIntrospector());
        converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(
                Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.json()
                        .annotationIntrospector(pairedIntrospectors)
                        .build()));
    }

    @Bean
    public DynamicJacksonAnnotationIntrospector introspector(Environment environment) {
        return new DynamicJacksonAnnotationIntrospector(environment);
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ObjectMapper getObjectMapper(DynamicJacksonAnnotationIntrospector introspector) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
        SerializationConfig serializationConfig = mapper.getSerializationConfig()
                .withInsertedAnnotationIntrospector(introspector);
        mapper.setConfig(serializationConfig);
        DeserializationConfig deserializationConfig = mapper.getDeserializationConfig()
                .withInsertedAnnotationIntrospector(introspector);
        mapper.setConfig(deserializationConfig);
        return mapper;
    }
}
```

And disable class in autoconfiguration for spring boot

```
spring:
  autoconfigure:
    exclude:
      - org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration
```

Examples

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class DynamicTestClass {
    @JsonProperty("${dynamic.property.name}")
    private String dynamicPropertyName;
}
```

```
@Slf4j
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK, classes = JiraSmCoreApplication.class)
@TestPropertySource("classpath:application-test.yml")
public class DynamicJacksonAnnotationIntrospectorTest {
    @Autowired
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mapper;

    @Test
    public void shouldFindNameForSerializationFromProperties() throws JsonProcessingException {
        DynamicTestClass bean = new DynamicTestClass();
        bean.setDynamicPropertyName("qwerty");
        log.info(mapper.getObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(bean));
    }
}
```

application-test.yml

```
spring:
  autoconfigure:
    exclude:
      - org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration

dynamic:
  property:
    name: overriddenName
```