# Switch field names between the received rest response and output to client

Tags: java, jackson

I have the following object and its value is set via a REST call as follows.

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class Benefit {

    @JsonProperty("text")
    private String headerText; // To note, I can't modify this headerText name
}
```

Data set from a rest call.

```
ResponseEntity<Benefit> response = 
    template.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, request, Benefit.class);
Benefit benefit = response.getBody();
```

The return value from the rest call is in following format which is why I annotated it as **text**.

```
{
    "text" : "some text"
}
```

After this, using this response, I am passing it down as a value to the client that called me.

 But when I send the information down, I don't want to name it as text.
I want to call it as **description**. Thus my response will be as follows:

```
{
    "description" : "some text"
}
```

Queries/ Pointers

1. Is there a way to do this without me having to manually set it?

2. This headerText is in use for different REST call. In that scenario, I need to both

receive the value as **text** and also return as **text**. (Thus that has no issues).

3. Preferably any possible solutions, should not affect above point 2.

4. But is ok if it will affect. I will go with an entirely new **Benefit2** Object to resolve this if there is a solution which affects point 2.

One possible way to do this is to set the value to another variable and pass that down as follows only for the particular rest call.

 But finding it very cumbersome as follows.

*Add a new field called description*

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class Benefit {

    @JsonProperty("text")
    private String headerText;

    // add a new field 
    private String description;
}
```

*After the rest call, do the following:*

```
Benefit benefit = response.getBody();
benefit.setDescription(benefit.getHeadlineText);
benefit.setHeaderText(null);
```

Any better ways?

To clarify on the flow:

1. Client calls my service
2. My service calls another service and got back:

   {
   "text" : "some text"
   }
3. I then return the following back to the client.

   {
   "description" : "some text"
   }

Thoughts after discussion.

Intention to use this object in both places, when calling rest and when returning response to client.

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class TestBenefit extends Benefit {

    @Getter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    @JsonProperty("text")
    private String text;
    
    private String description;

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.description = text;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Over time I learned that trying to use one object for multiple purposes in these scenarios is more trouble than it is worth. You should create objects that cater to your requests and responses appropriately. Use base classes if necessary. Also, I wouldn't call it `Benefit2`. :o) Name your classes, to some degree, for what they are used for. You could do something like...

```
class BenefitForOtherPurpose extends Benefit {

   @JsonProperty('description')
   public String getHeaderText() {
     return this.headerText;
   }
}
```

To that end, I don't think there is a way using the Jackson API to adjust the `@JsonProperty` value dynamically short of some reflection kung-fu that, again, is likely more trouble than it is worth. And there's nothing I know of in the Jackson API to conditionally set that outside of this complex solution:

[Conditional JsonProperty using Jackson with Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35089257/conditional-jsonproperty-using-jackson-with-spring-boot)

Comment: Get your point. I do plan on creating a new Object to map this after consideration so that I could avoid bothering with other rest calls. But to also do it for the response from 1 rest call and another to send out to client. So verbose... cos I would kinda essentially be duplicating objects less one field. (Benefit Object has 8 other fields which I need).

Comment: That's what I meant by base class (subclass). Or just extend and override your Benefit class. You can put the @JsonProperty on the getters as well. So if you extend Benefit, you could just override the getHeaderText() with a different property.

Comment: Taking your suggestion in mind went with the amended solution above under "Thoughts after discussion.". Could I get your thoughts.